# Facebook API - Unsupported get request for page/post insights

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know there's a multitude of questions regarding Facebook's SDK and API and this specific error response, however none of them seem to answer my question.

I run a Facebook page and until a couple of days ago I had some code running that would collect the `insights` data for each post on my Facebook page.

This is what I was doing:

```
define('FB_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'omitted'); // Never expires, has permission to read insight data (and more)
define('FB_APP_ID', 'omitted'); // ID of my Facebook App
define('FB_APP_SECRET', 'omitted'); // Secret for App
define('FB_ACCOUNT_ID', 'omitted'); // Facebook ID of my page
define('FB_REQUEST', 'insights/post_impressions_unique,post_consumptions_by_type,post_negative_feedback_by_type,post_consumptions,post_story_adds_by_action_type');

// .. Require Facebook SDK (Using composer)
// .. Other processing


// Initialise the Facebook SDK with our credentials and permanent access token.
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => FB_APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2'
]);
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken(FB_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN);


// .. Grab some posts from my database
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $postId = $post['id'];
    $request = FB_ACCOUNT_ID . '_' . $postId . '/' . FB_REQUEST;
    // Request will now contain something like...
    // <PAGE_ID>_<POST_ID>/insights/post_impressions_unique,post_consumptions_by_type,post_negative_feedback_by_type,post_consumptions,post_story_adds_by_action_type

    try {
        $fb->get($response); // This line fails and throw exception

        // .. Rest of my processing
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        die("\nEXCEPTION: {$e->getMessage()}\n{$e->getTraceAsString()}");
    }
}
```

The above code was working great until a couple of days ago when I noticed my stats weren't pulling in. After some investigation and playing around using the Graph API Explorer I have found that I get the following output:

> EXCEPTION: Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

And using the Graph API Explorer:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "XXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

No matter what I have tried I don't seem to be able to get the insights for a single post on a page again. I've tried playing with the Graph API Explorer, trying a number of combinations but don't seem to be able to get anything back. I've even tried generating new tokens with the correct permissions to no avail. Some of the combinations I've tried:

- `<POST_ID>/insights` - `(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher`
- `<PAGE_ID>/insights` - Shows all insights for page, nothing about each specific post

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Yeah, I know but I always make sure I include it. I've included via the SDK and I've made sure to include it in the Graph API Explorer too

Answer (score 2):

Other than always having a correct access token in every request, the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights

contain a hint:

> /{post-id}/insights (Page posts only)*
>   *Note: The Graph API object {post-id} needs to be **specified in the same format returned by the API call to fetch a list of page posts** - *do not attempt to split or combine other IDs to form a post ID*

Baseline: Try to just use

```
$request = $postId . '/' . FB_REQUEST;
```

instead of

```
$request = FB_ACCOUNT_ID . '_' . $postId . '/' . FB_REQUEST;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried what you suggested and mentioned that in the first bullet in my question. I get an `OAuthException` with the message `(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher` when I try `<POST_ID>/insights`

Comment: According to the v2.5 docs this should work. And how would I know that `<POST_ID>` corresponds to `$postId`. That's not in the code.

Comment: Tried with one of my page's posts, and there's no error message returned

Comment: That's odd. I've even tried running `<PAGE_ID>/posts` in the Graph API Explorer, clicking a random post ID (Which shows that post's details) and then simply appending `/insights` to the request. That however, displays a different error: `An unknown error has occurred.`

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Are you using v2.5? And does the acces token contain the `read_insights` permission?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `v2.5` in the Graph API Explorer as we speak. Yeah, my token does have `read_insights`. From the token debugging tool it has: `user_likes, email, ads_read, read_insights, manage_pages, read_custom_friendlists, public_profile`

Comment: I've even tried getting a new access token with that permission and I still get the same error

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make any difference. Oddly enough, I'm now finding that certain `<page_id>_<post_id>/insights` combinations are working, but **only** for v2.2. I get the same errors using v2.5. Perhaps my SDK isn't actually using 2.2 when I'm telling it to. **Edit:** It only seems to be working on v2.2 when I generate a new token

Comment: Thanks for that @Tobi. At least I'm not going crazy! Cheers.

Comment: ..and just like that, after hours of trying and testing different things locally, my code has just started working again, without any changes being pushed live! Thanks for your help and suggestions

Comment: That's why "Move fast and break things" is the FB motto... You're welcome. If you like give me any upvote :-)